# Turning my working Haskell code into proper Haskell code

Tags: haskell

I'm trying to get into haskell so I'm messing around and I wrote my own elem function but it seems so clunky. What would be the haskell way to accomplish this?

```
elem' x xs = 
    if null xs 
        then False
        else 
            if x == (head xs)
                then True 
                else elem' x (tail xs)
```

Comment: It does look very clunky `:p` Haskell is so expressive that you can often get by with one-liners. Look up [`elem`'s actual implementation](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.7.0.1/docs/src/GHC-List.html#elem) and be awed.

Answer (score 8):

You can use pattern matching to simplify the code

```
elem' _ [] = False 
elem ' x1 (x2:_) | x1 == x2 = True
elem' x (_:ret) = elem' x rest
```

or you could take a completely different approach

```
elem' x = not . null . filter (== x)
```

(by laziness, it won't go past the found element, so you can do `elem' 4 [1..]`)

---

For those inclined, there is also a foldr approach

```
elem' x = foldr ((||) . (x==)) False
```

which is also lazy.

Answer (score 5):

As a manual recursion:

```
elem' :: Eq a => a -> [a] -> Bool
elem' x [] = False
elem' x (y:ys) = x == y || elem' x ys
```

Or use the `any` function:

```
elem' x xs = any (==x) xs
```

or

```
elem' x = any (==x)
```

or even

```
elem' = any . (==)
```

(though personally I don't think that last one reads as nicely).

Answer (score 1):

First, if you use pattern matching, you can take out `null`, `head` and `tail`:

```
elem x    []  = False
elem x (y:ys) = ...
```

That alone makes the code shorter.

(Also, certain people dislike `head` and `tail` because they throw exceptions if the list is empty. Using the pattern-matching approach above, there is no possibility of such a problem.)

Second, `if foo then True else bar` can by simplified to `foo || bar`. This is OK because of laziness; if `foo` is true, then `bar` will never be computed (so in this example, the recursive loop will terminate).

```
elem x (y:ys) = x == y || elem x ys
```

Several other answers have also mentioned that you can use the built-in `any` function, in which case the entire thing becomes a trivial 1-liner:

```
elem x = any (== x)
```